# Blocked due to other 4xx issue in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, error, crawl-errors

I have problems with error "Blocked due to other 4xx issue" in Google Search Console. I dont know how to fix that and what is problem. I just have on website "call button" for customers and GSC have issues with this. Do I need to add that "page" to sitemap?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the url in the browser ?  Does it give an error ?

Comment: Are you expecting that URL to have content that you want to have indexed?

Comment: @RohitGupta Yes it gives. This:
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no its just "call" button.

Comment: So why do you care if Google finds it blocked?

Comment: I thought it needs to be fixed for better searching in Google.

Comment: And idk why but I have now in google search console this text: "URL is not on Google
This page is not indexed. Pages that aren't indexed can't be served on Google. See the details below to learn why it wasn't indexed." And before i had "Indexed. but not submitted in sitemap" and I dont kbow how its possible, because I have one-page website, just scrolling. I added sitemap to the website.

Comment: I meant on main page that texts now. not this "call" button.